# Why does Sequelize pauze after 3120 records?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite, caching, sequelize.js

I've got a system written in Nodejs which first has to import records from very big csv files into a database. Using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) as my ORM I created a simple model as follows:

```
"use strict";
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('mm', 'root', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: true,
    pool: {max: 5, min: 0, idle: 100000},
});
const Index = sequelize.define('index', {
    value: {type: Sequelize.FLOAT}
});
```

I then wrote the following code to loop over the lines in the file, interpret the lines, and write them to the database:

```
let readline = require('readline');
let moment = require('moment');

let lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('files/price_index.csv')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    let splitted = line.split(',');
    let dt = moment(parseInt(splitted[0]));
    let value = parseFloat(splitted[1]);
    console.log(dt.format(), value);
    Index.create({value: value, createdAt: dt});
});
```

This works ok, but it pauses for about 3 seconds after every 3120 records. I tried both sqlite and mysql, but it always pauses after exactly 3120 records.

Seeing that Sequelize starts the logging of the insert queries also after those 3120 records, I presume the cause of this behaviour is some sort of caching mechanism which puts all queries in a queue until it either has nothing to do, or if it hits that magic query cache limit which is exactly 3120 records.

I tried increasing `pool.max` number in the initialisation of Sequelize, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Can anybody either confirm my caching idea, or explain me what the true reason is of this behaviour? Can I somehow change this behaviour so that it has a consistant throughput? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think 3120 lines will be [the high water mark for the `createReadStream` buffer which is 64KiB](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options). Node will back off reading when the buffer is full.

It looks like the 3120 `line` events all run on the same Node event tick so you get 3120 lines processed and 3120 async `Index.create` calls scheduled for the next tick. So you end up with huge chunks of processing to do on each side. Either reading and scheduling the queries, or dealing with the mass of scheduled queries.

When the 3120 `line` event functions are done, some garbage collection happens and the 3120 sequelize `create` calls that were scheduled get a chance to do their thing. This is the "pause" in the data, but Node is still processing. All the `create` calls take a few seconds to complete, then some more garbage collection and back to the next chunk of csv data and all it's `line` events. The process goes back and forth like that.

In a csv file with 10000 lines I see ~ 3 queries able to run before all 10000 rows of csv data have been read and scheduled for insert.

#### Consistent Throughput

You probably want to use a [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) with smaller chunks. Then  block reads based on sequelize inserts completing. You may need to do the line processing your self rather than using [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_pause). If the csv file fits in memory just read the whole thing in as the scheduling will be easier.

Maybe use something like [`queue`](https://github.com/jessetane/queue) to manage the inserts, allowing up to your sequelize pool `max` as the `concurrency`. Then once the `length` of the queue is low enough, allow reads to happen again.

I don't know if the end result will be much quicker though, might end up pretty similar.